# What is the application flow after Google Store update?

Tags: android, service, google-play

I'm trying to understand what exactly happens after my app gets updated on the users devices.
As of course the `'MainActivity'` isn't launched, I am wondering about the services.
I have one `START_STICKY` service and one which is not, does the `START_STICKY` auto-start after the update, what about the other ?

Is there any way of testing this behavior without waiting for a real `Play Store` update ?

I looked for a documentation regarding this issue but couldn't find anything related.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick test. Not sure how close this is to an actual update on the Play Store or if it is in any way comparable, but here goes:

I have created a simple app that starts two services on the click of a button, one `START_STICKY` one `START_NOT_STICKY`.

Both services create a notification in `onStartCommand()` and show a version number.

I create one release APK, change the version number in Manifest and notification, and create another release APK. I've copied the two APKs onto the phone and disconnected the phone.

I've manually installed the first APK on the phone, started the app, clicked the button, two notifications appear. Installed the second APK, without starting the app. The two notifications disappeared and did not re-appear either. Opened the app, clicked the button, both notifications appeared with the new version number.

From this it appears that neither service will be restarted automatically after an app update.

You could also publish your app on Google Play as an Alpha version and test an update of your app without annoying general users.

Comment: Thank you for the test but i'm not sure it reflects the behavior of an update from Play Store. I guess ill have to actually upload to alpha / beta and test it, the thing is, it takes several hours for each update to take place while if I want to do small changes and check again, it is not possible.